# AWS Transcribe | Can't create custom vocabulary using table via SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, speech-recognition, amazon-transcribe

There are two options provided by AWS Transcribe to create a custom vocabulary. For more info [Custom Vocabularies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transcribe/latest/dg/how-vocabulary.html)

- Using List
- Using Table

I can create custom vocabularies in both ways via AWS console but when it comes to AWS Java SDK, I can create it using a list. In the case of *"using table"* it gives me an error

> **Failure reason**
>
> The vocabulary that you’re trying to create contains invalid
> characters or incorrectly formatted terms. See the developer guide for
> more information.

```
    AmazonTranscribe transcribe = AmazonTranscribeClient.builder().build();
    CreateVocabularyRequest vocabularyRequest = new CreateVocabularyRequest();
    vocabularyRequest.setLanguageCode(LanguageCode.EnUS.toString());
    vocabularyRequest.setPhrases(Arrays.asList("Phrase\tIPA\tSoundsLike\tDisplayAs", "helloooo\t\thello\thailo"));
    vocabularyRequest.setVocabularyName("table-clone");
    CreateVocabularyResult vocabularyResult = transcribe.createVocabulary(vocabularyRequest);
```

But I can create the same vocab *using table* (via AWS console) so I don't think that there is an issue with my vocab.

**Case 1: Via AWS Console**

One more important thing to notice is that when we create vocab ***using list view***, AWS appends an end delimiter (**ENDOFDICTIONARYTRANSCRIBE**). But it doesn't append this delimiter when we create vocab using ***table view***

**Case 2: Via AWS Java SDK**

End delimiter is appended at the end of the file in both cases (list and table). I think this can be the issue.

**To Sum Up**

I want to create custom vocabulary **using table** via AWS Java SDK. I can create the same via AWS Console but failed to do so via Java SDK.

Comment: In the console, you have to put the file in S3 first, before doing table ; wouldn't surprise me if you need to do the same here

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom vocabulary using table, by uploading the .txt file to AWS S3 and then using the URI of the object as a value to VocabularyFileUri key.

You can do the same task, by uploading a file in list format on AWS Console, but if you need to use tables, S3 is the way to go!